# Basic mySQL - Don't know how to show all results including 0

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Ok. This is a homework exercise . I've tried looking up everything and can't figure out the error.
The schema is as follows:

```
course{
 course_id
 title
 dept
}

section{
 course_id
 semester
 year
}
```

The course table has all the offered courses.
The section table has what courses are offered, past and future.

I'm to list how many times each course has been offered. Even if it has never been offered before. (Including zeros).

So. What I have so far are sub queries that do each part separately but I'm failing miserably at merging the two. (That's where I need your help.) (Sidenote: I'm new to sql, sorry if a query looks painfully inefficient)

So I know how to get all the courses and sort them.

```
SELECT course_id FROM course ORDER BY course_id;
```

I also know how to count all the number of times a course has been offered.

```
SELECT course_id, COUNT( course_id )FROM section GROUP BY course_id;
```

So I thought, use the two sub-queries to make the result!

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT course_id, COUNT( course_id ) FROM section GROUP BY course_id
) AS T1 
NATURAL JOIN 
(
SELECT course_id FROM course ORDER BY course_id
) as T2;
```

But that ignores the courses that have a count of 0. I've tried using IFNULL but I may be using it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do *(from most to less preferable)*

```
SELECT c.course_id, COUNT(s.course_id) total
  FROM course c LEFT JOIN section s 
    ON c.course_id = s.course_id
 GROUP BY c.course_id;
```

or

```
SELECT c.course_id, COALESCE(total, 0) total
  FROM course c LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT course_id, COUNT(*) total
    FROM section
   GROUP BY course_id
) s
    ON c.course_id = s.course_id;
```

or

```
SELECT course_id,
(
  SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM section
   WHERE course_id = c.course_id
) total
  FROM course c;
```

**Note:** that in the very first query you have to count `course_id`s from `section` table rather than from `section` when using `LEFT JOIN`.

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/88379/5)** demo

Answer (score 0):

You just want to base your query off of the sections, and LEFT JOIN which tallies up even sections that have not yet had courses on the right side of the join

```
SELECT section.course_id, COUNT(course.id) FROM section
    LEFT JOIN course ON course.course_id = section.course_id
    GROUP BY section.course_id
```

Comment: I just solved it using my horribly large queries. I just needed to use a LEFT JOIN. Also I tried yours. It just returns one of the course ids. I then tried adding group by course_id. The issue there is that it add the 0 cases.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean, I would suggest attempting to use the latest updated answer. Regardless, if you've solved the problem that's great!

Comment: Basically section might have { A A B B C } and course will list each one once. { A B C D } and I need to the out put formatted to { (A,2) , (B,2) (C,1) (D,0) }. Bryan's skips the (D,0)

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer I managed to figure out that works.

```
SELECT T1.course_id , IFNULL( t2Count , 0 ) FROM 
(
SELECT course_id FROM course ORDER BY course_id
) AS T1 
LEFT JOIN 
(
SELECT course_id, COUNT( course_id ) as t2Count FROM section GROUP BY course_id
) as T2 
ON 
T1.course_id=T2.course_id;
```

I'll pick the first person that gets the same result as this with a shorter query. (Not counting variable names)